# Replace github repository on pub.dev with other github repository

Tags: flutter, dart, publish

I just published a new flutter package to pub.dev with link to my personal github public repository.

And now I want to change it to my company github public repository. Is it possible? and how to do it?

Note:
I have tried to move my code from my personal github to my company github, add some feature, increase the version. And published it to pub.dev.
The version etc is updated on pub.dev, and also when I run 'flutter pub get' on my local pc, however the source code link on pub.dev is still linked to my personal github, which is the old version.

Thanks

Comment: When you updated your package version, did you update the `homepage` line in your `pubspec.yaml` file to point to the new repository location?

Comment: Oh. I did not do that. I think it would solve the issue. Thanks a lots.